# status bar and navigation bar becomes visible in immersive mode when searching in listview from the toolbar search

Tags: android, user-interface, toolbar, user-experience, android-immersive

I have an activity where the theme is set to
    `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

And i have used `toolbar` search for searching a `listview`.

But when i start writing something in the `toolbar` search area the status bar and navigation bar become visible.

What i want to do is to search the list but the status bar on the top should stay hidden.

check out the pics where the status bar overlaps the toolbar..[normal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZoDS.png), [when writing something in search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dGX8.png)

This is the layout for the activity with a toolbar and a list view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the menu item for searching

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.sample.YourActivity" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"

    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Searchable layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="search it">
</searchable>
```

search bar implementation in onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListner = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListner);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain bit easier ?

Comment: i don't be able to get this **when i start writing something in the toolbar search area the status bar and navigation bar become visible ?**

Comment: its like when i start searching for something the keyboard comes out but along with that i also see the status bar on top overlapping the toolbar .plz see image that i have linked

Comment: Can i see your XML code.

Comment: thats all the code you need